# SQL Syntax Error id suddenly equals zero

Tags: php, mysql

Does anybody know what could be wrong here?

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
echo $q." "; // $q=2
$d = $_GET['d'];
echo $d." "; //$d=3priority
$m = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $d);
echo $m." "; //$m = priority
$s = intval($_GET['d']);
echo $s;// $s = 3
$sql = "UPDATE form SET $m = $q WHERE id = $s";
$result = $conn->query($sql); 
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {echo "das";}
else{
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

I get the Error Message :

> UPDATE form SET = 0 WHERE id = 0 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '= 0 WHERE id = 0' at line 1

However if I echo the $m/$q/$s/$d thy show the right values. But somehow they get changed to 0 in the sql statement.

Would be nice if you could help me out :)

Comment: learn first update syntax

Comment: In your sql query check the value of $m. It seems that $m is empty

Comment: is the update syntax different?

Comment: @krishnpatel Whats wrong with the Update syntax?

Comment: UPDATE tableName SET  ET $m = $q WHERE id = $s

Comment: @MUNISHKUMAR they all see to be empty, but when I echo them they show the right values, however as soon as they are in the sql they all are 0.

Comment: Try this `$sql = "UPDATE form SET" . $m . "=" . $q . " WHERE id =" . $s;`

Comment: @krishn patel don't confuse with **form**, It is a table name.

Comment: @MUNISHKUMAR k ty it works now ^^ idk i also tried thi before with no succes however so i just copied pasted it and now its works ^^ ty again <3

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$sql = "UPDATE form SET" . $m . "=" . $q . " WHERE id =" . $s;
```